# How to fix jQuery mobile and Codeigniter redirect issue?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I am building a Mobile site using jQuery mobile framework and php Codeigniter framework.
On the website's home page, I am asking user to select few options in form and submit it. On submission of form, I am checking the values submitted using Codeigniter input->post() method and then redirecting to a specific page.

So e.g. current page is

```
www.xyz.com
```

Then on form submission, I am getting redirected to

```
www.xyz.com/list
```

The redirect code under codeigniter I have used is

```
redirect(base_url()."list");
```

Now the problem here occurring is, I am getting redirected fine but the page URL in address bar is still the Home page URL. So if I try to refresh this **List** page, it will load up the home page. It seems this is some misbehavior of jquery framework ajax method.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to redirect in this form:

```
redirect('controller_name/function_name');
```

You can try in this form

```
redirect('list');
```

If the list is the name of class.

Comment: I want to use a whole URL like www.xyz.com/list/city/state... like this as I have passed few parameters to this url plus I have also done URL routings. so it's a kind of MUST to redirect to a full url

Comment: So, you can redirect with parameter also:
redirect('class_name/function_name/parameter/');

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the form declaration. You have to set data-ajax=false to the form. It will be like this

`<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" **data-ajax="false"**>`